# Why do I not see print inside my lua function

Tags: lua

My question has multiple parts but firstly here is my sample lua code (**test.lua**):

```
local traceback = debug.traceback

local inspect = require('inspect')

local foo = "function nop(); print('this is war'); return true; end"

local f = loadstring(foo)

local result = f()

print(result)

local status, val= xpcall(function () return f() end,debug.traceback)

print('status .. ' .. tostring(status))

print(val)
```

So,

1. When I run `local result = f()`. I still see the `result` value as `nil`
2. When the function `f` is executed. Why don't I see the `print` o/p .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chunk of code in `foo` which you load into `f` doesn't return any values.

It defines a function but that's it.

If you want to return the function from the chunk when it is run you need to add `return nop` to the end of the string.